# CXF-RS throwing No operation matching request path /create is found,

Tags: web-services, rest, cxf

I developed the JAX-RS webservices using CXF framework and i deployed in Jboss6.
While i try to access the application using the following URL http://localhost:8080/UPCServiceLayer/services/upcLineOfBusiness/create from my HTML page (using POST method only) i am getting following error in the server console

```
No operation matching request path /create is found,
```

The following is my cxf.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd 
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import  resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:../upc-spring-dao.xml" />
    <jaxrs:server id="upcLineOfBusinessRestServiceServer" address="/upcLineOfBusiness">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="upcLineOfBusinessRestService" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>
    <bean id="upcLineOfBusinessRestService"
        class="com.tecnotree.upc.services.restservices.impl.UpcLineOfBusinessRestServiceImpl">
        <property name="upcLineOfBusinessDao">
            <ref bean="upcLineOfBusinessDao" />
        </property>
        <property name="upcUserDao">
            <ref bean="upcUserDao" />
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The following is my resource class

```java
@Path("/")
public classUpcLineOfBusinessRestService {
    @POST
    @ConsumeMime("application/xml")
    @ProduceMime("application/xml")
    @Path("/create")
    public UpcLineOfBusinessEntity createUpcLineOfBusinessEntity(
            UpcLineOfBusinessEntity upcLineOfBusinessEntity)
            throws GenericUpcException
```

and i declared CXF servlet in my web.xml file also.

```xml
 <servlet>
            <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm somewhat surprised to see the `@ProduceMime` and `@ConsumeMime` annotations there; the current style is to use `@Produces` and `@Consumes` instead (from the JAX-RS standard). This is important, because CXF uses the content type annotations as part of its method matching process, which could make things fail to match (and hence give a confusing error message).

(Also, are you sure you're POSTing “`application/xml`” to the server? Get that wrong and you'll also have no-match errors. Try turning up the level of logging on the server to see what its actually trying to do during matching; that helps with tracking down this sort of problem but can't be on by default as it is *very* chatty.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason i am using @ProduceMime is Jboss6 bundled with cxf2.3.1 , in this version i can use only the jsr311-api-0.8-1.3.0.jar . This jar file only having old classes for MIME types. How to post the data as application/xml ? I need to set the content type for that HTML page as application/xml? Here i am using plain HTML form to post the data .

Comment: For time being i just changed the Consumes annotation value to application/x-www-form-urlencoded . After that i am trying to call that resource using HTML form POST method but i am getting an new exception No message body reader found for request class : UpcLineOfBusinessEntity, ContentType : application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Based on google i understand we need to configure JAXB in CXF. So i added the following line in cxf.xml ......

Comment: <bean id="jaxbProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider">
  <property name="marshallerProperties" ref="propertiesMap" />
 </bean>
 <util:map id="propertiesMap">
  <entry key="jaxb.formatted.output">
   <value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value>
  </entry>
 </util:map> But i am getting same exception. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

These four lines look OK to me:

```
<url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>

<jaxrs:server id="upcLineOfBusinessRestServiceServer" address="/upcLineOfBusiness">

@Path("/")

@Path("/create")
```

Togehter they should match `/services/upcLineOfBusiness/create`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer . If i try to open a WADL file http://localhost:8080/UPCServiceLayer/services/upcLineOfBusiness?_wadl&_type=xml i am getting following exception 15:36:55,206 WARN  [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils] .No operation matching request path / is found, ContentType : */*, Accept : text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,.
15:36:55,231 WARN  [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper] WebApplicationException has been caught : no cause is available

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have used proper HTTP method while calling your API (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE)